# Analytical way of describing centred difference coefficients

Tags: taylor-expansion, finite-differences

I am trying to find an analytical way to describe the finite difference coefficients of various degrees of accuracy of centred difference schemes that approximate the second derivative. For example, a second order approximation is:

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} p(x) = \frac{p(x-h) - 2 p(x) + p(h+1)}{2h} + O(x^2)$$

so the first set of coefficients is $\{\frac{1}{2}, -1, \frac{1}{2} \}$. Likewise, you can extend this method to higher orders. I made a table of the first 8 sets of coefficients:

[image]

The only way I know to derive these is to use Lagrangian interpolation, and then solve a system of $n + 1$ equations (where $n$ is the order of accuracy). However, this doesn't really get you any closer to an analytical way of describing it. There might be another, more analytical approach (Taylor series expansions?), or a formula that computes this for arbitrary orders, but I don't know it.

I am fully aware of the possibility that such an analytical representation may not exist, but I'd be interested to know if there is a way to prove *that*.

Comment: What is a "centred difference scheme"? What exactly are the coefficients you list above? What would you like to get?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I elaborated a bit more on that. Sorry to assume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An interesting and synthetic way to get the weights for a finite difference approximation of the $m$-derivative of a function, given its values at $n+1$ equally spaced vertices, is given by the Fornberg formula.

Take the $n$ coefficients of the Taylor series expansion around $x=1$ of the function

$$x^s log(x)^m$$

where $s h$ is the distance, from the leftmost vertex of the stencil, of the point at which you want approximate the derivative and $h$ is the grid spacing; if you want a centered approximation $s = n/2$; $s$ need not to be a whole number.

In *Mathematica* you can implement the formula with the following one-line:

```
FiniteDifferenceWeights[m_Integer /; IntegerQ[m], (* derivative order *)
                        n_Integer /; IntegerQ[n], (* stencil width *)
                        s_ /; NumericQ[s],        (* point of evaluation  *)
                        h_: 1] :=                 (* grid spacing *)
 Block[{x}, CoefficientList[Normal[Series[x^s Log[x]^m, {x, 1, n}]/h^m], x]]
```

directly adapted from the Fornberg formula to be a more robust function definition and to accept the mesh width $h$.

For example, to get a sixth-order centred difference approximation of the second derivate, at a grid spacing of 1:

```
> FiniteDifferenceWeights[2, 6, 3, 1]

{1/90, -3/20, 3/2, -49/18, 3/2, -3/20, 1/90}
```

Maybe you can start from here to prove what you need.

> Fornberg, B. "Fast Generation of Weights in Finite Difference
>   Formulas." In Recent Developments in Numerical Methods and Software
>   for ODEs/DAEs/PDEs. World Scientific, 1992.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, thank you ever so much! I took the liberty to add some comments and an example to code, as this it is not immediately obvious how to use it for those not proficient with  *Mathematica*.

Comment: Glad to be helpful.

Comment: @Yellow But I don't completely agree with the fact that $n$ is always the approximation order. If I'm not wrong, if the unknown function is smooth enough the order of accuracy should be $n-m+1$ if $s \neq n/2$ and $n-m+2$ if $s=n/2$...

Comment: You're absolutely right, that was a sloppy comment of mine. Oops. :-)